# How to delete columns with formulas in Excel

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, excel-2007

I am new to Excel sheets, I have some work on Excel in my Excel sheet there are 92,000 columns i what to delete the columns which have cells length greater than 8 digits in phone number. 
Below is example of the Excel sheet:

[image]

I what to delete the Columns which has phone number length 9.
by the above example delete A3, A5 Columns.

Comment: By "columns," do you mean *rows*?  So in your example, you want to delete rows 3 and 5?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you have 92,000 rows of data? I'm going to assume so.

Unfortunately, you can't delete things using normal formulas. This could easily be accomplished using a VBA macro, but I doubt you want to get into that right now. As a temporary solution, you can automatically hide all the rows where the phone number is more than 8 characters by doing the following:

In your first blank column (which looks like C according to your sample), in the second row, put this formula: `=LEN($A2)`. Copy this formula down to the end of your data by hover your mouse over the bottom-right corner of that cell and double-clicking. In your header row, just label the column "Number Length" or something like that.

This will return the length of the values in each row in A. Now, select your entire header row (row 1 in your case) by clicking on the "1" (the row name). Then, go to the "Data" ribbon and click the "Filter" button. You will now see drop-down menus appear next to each header name.

Click on the drop-down menu that appeared above your "Number Length" column you just created. Hover over "Number Filters" and then click "Less Than." In the first field that pops up (to the right of "Less Than") enter 9. Then click OK.

If you did everything correctly, all rows where the length of the phone number is more than 8 will be hidden. They will not be *deleted* , but they will not be visible until you remove that filter.

If you really do want to physically delete the rows, I suggest reading up on VBA, specifically the `Len` function, and `For` loops. Try something, then if it doesn't work, post another question with the [Excel-VBA] tag and the code you tried.